# Applying the rotation between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, to vector $\vec{c}$

Tags: 3d, rotations, quaternions

Given 3 unit vectors $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, and $\vec{c}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I would like to compute the rotation between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

Then apply that rotation to $\vec{c}$ to obtain a new vector $\vec{d}$.

$\vec{c}$ is not coplanar with $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

I attempted this with both rotation matrices and quaternions, computing the rotation between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, but when I apply it to $\vec{c}$ the dot product is not equal, e.g.:

$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} \ne \vec{c} \cdot \vec{d}$

Because $\vec{c}$ is not coplanar with $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

> Should I compute the rotation for each axis independently and then
>   recombine them? I'm not sure what the correct approach is here.

Context:

I'm trying to correlate the rotation from the center pixel of an image $\vec{a}$ to a point of interest on the image $\vec{b}$. Given that I know the cameras focal length I can compute the unit vectors in *pixel space*. I have the cameras angle of focus in *world coordinates* $\vec{c}$ and want to angle the camera by the same amount such that it is pointing directly at the point of interest, new vector $\vec{d}$

Comment: In general there are an infinite number of 3-dimensional rotation transformations that will take $\vec a$ to $\vec b$, so you have to specify some other constraint. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Carmeister That is true, but there is one rotation which stands out: $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ define a plane, and if the rotation is around the normal vector of that plane, then it's unique.

Comment: I'm trying to correlate the rotation from the center pixel of an image $\vec{a}$ to a point of interest on the image $\vec{b}$, given that I know the cameras focal length I can compute the unit vectors. I have the cameras angle of focus in world coordinates $\vec{c}$ and want to angle the camera by the same amount such that it is pointing directly at the point of interest, new vector $\vec{d}$.

Comment: It would be advisable to put this bit of context into your question. It makes it more interesting for people to answer (and adding context _might_ stop the infantile close-zealots, though I wouldn't wager large sums on that).

Comment: @Arthur: that only works if $a$ and $b$ are distinct. It's pretty obvious what to do if they're identical (the identity rotation), but if you write a computer program, it'll likely generate an error for this case unless you consider it explicitly.

Comment: @John Huges If I understand the OP correctly, $\vec{a}=\vec{b}$ is not a use case.

Comment: It may not be an *anticipated* use-case, but my experience in graphics/vision says it'll arrive more often than expected. For instance, if $b$ is some point you're tracking, every now and then it'll *happen* to fall right at the image center, and you'd like your program to still do something reasonable. At any rate, it's not excluded in the problem that OP actually asked (rather than the context that motivated it), so I think it's worth considering.

Comment: If I’ve understood what it is you’re trying to accomplish correctly, then you just need to transform the computed rotation axis back into world coordinates.

Comment: @amd this sounds promising, can you expand on your comment some? I'm not sure I follow, though I'm trying.

Comment: It looks like you’re trying to find the real-world camera rotation that matches the rotation that you computed from the image. This will be the composition of the computed rotation with the rotation part of the world-to-camera transformation. The method for computing the latter rotation depends on what you have to work with. You have the camera’s line of sight in world coordinates, but there’s still one degree of freedom left: the camera’s rotation about that line of sight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you use [Rodrigues rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula). I'm pretty certain there's an equivalent quaternion formulation, but... well, I'm not Professor Quaternion. =D In this case, $\alpha$ and $\theta$ *are* equal, and since $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are unit vectors, we have $\sin\theta=|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|$ and $\cos\theta=\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}$, giving the final result
$$\vec{d}=(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})\,\vec{c}+|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|\,\vec{k}\times\vec{c}+(1-\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})\,(k\cdot\vec{c})\,\vec{k},$$ where $$\vec{k}=\frac{\vec{a}\times\vec{b}}{|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|}$$ is your (normalized) axis of rotation.
Edit: the formulation
$$\vec{d}=(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})\,\vec{c}+(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})\times\vec{c}+\frac{((\vec{a}\times\vec{b})\cdot\vec{c})\,\vec{a}\times\vec{b}}{1+\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}$$ avoids the problem worrying @John Huges... but it doesn't resolve another one: $\vec{a}=-\vec{b}$. In that case, it's really not clear what should happen.

Comment: This approach seems to have the same problem that I've encountered with my other attempts. I think the axis of rotation applied to $\vec{c}$ is incorrect (I'm still tring to wrap my head around this). When I apply this $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} \ne \vec{c} \cdot \vec{d}$ Using $a=[0.58,0.58,0.58]$, $b=[0,0,1]$, $c=[0,1,0]$ I get $d=[-0.21, 0.79, 0.58]$ whereas I think I should be expecting $[-0.58, 0.58, 0.58]$ based on a visual inspection.

Comment: @David Parks That's true, you could have $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = \vec{c} \cdot \vec{d}$ only if $\vec{c}$ were coplanar with $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. But what I wrote is the result if you rotate $\vec{c}$ around the same axis (not perpendicular to $\vec{c}$, then). So I suspect the operation you want isn't exactly the rotation you describe.

Comment: I believe you're right, I am not describing the rotation correctly, I fear that I don't know what I don't know still. Ultimately I want the change between $\vec{a}$ & $\vec{b}$ that occurs when I compute vectors in *pixel space* (I see a point of interest on the screen) to apply in *world space* (the camera now physically points at that point of interest based on its screen coordinates).